# Print 1 to 1000 in C++ without semi-colons

Tags: popularity-contest, restricted-source, c++

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568645/printing-1-to-1000-without-loop-or-conditionals) popular question, present your solution which prints the numbers 1 to 1000 (all of them, not the string "1 to 1000" verbatim or something funny) in C++ without using any semi-colons. Unlike the original question, you may use conditionals and loops.

Solutions not requiring any compiler flags are preferred. Please mention any you use if you go against this. Undefined behaviour is allowed, so please specify the compiler and version you're using. Preference will be given to clever solutions. This is *not* a shortest code contest.

(I have a solution, which I'll post in 24 hours if a similar solution isn't posted before then.)

Comment: what about your solution?

Comment: @Deb The if condition in my statement evaluated to false. :)

Comment: @macrog:May I know which of the solution makes that evaluation? :-)

Comment: There is also a [similar task in SPOJ](https://www.spoj.pl/problems/EXPR2/) which require you to code without semicolon.

Comment: Y CAnt use constructors since the question actually wants us to answer in c++ ..create 1000 objects ...everytime constructor gets called i++ ?? :)

Comment: @marcog: But show us your solution, please. I'm very interested on it.

Comment: I would laugh one day if this question was asked for scala.

Answer (score 35):

The semicolon is not needed if you know the magic word. And no need to go obfuscated.

My solution has the additional fanciness that it doesn't use any comma either ;)

```
#include <iostream>
#define Please(x) if (x) {}

int Number(int x)
{
    if (x > 1)
        Please(Number(x-1))
    Please(std::cout << " " << x)
}

int main()
{
    Please(Number(1000))
}
```

Comment: This one is underrated.

Answer (score 29):

```
#error "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 262 263 264 265 266 267 268 269 270 271 272 273 274 275 276 277 278 279 280 281 282 283 284 285 286 287 288 289 290 291 292 293 294 295 296 297 298 299 300 301 302 303 304 305 306 307 308 309 310 311 312 313 314 315 316 317 318 319 320 321 322 323 324 325 326 327 328 329 330 331 332 333 334 335 336 337 338 339 340 341 342 343 344 345 346 347 348 349 350 351 352 353 354 355 356 357 358 359 360 361 362 363 364 365 366 367 368 369 370 371 372 373 374 375 376 377 378 379 380 381 382 383 384 385 386 387 388 389 390 391 392 393 394 395 396 397 398 399 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 419 420 421 422 423 424 425 426 427 428 429 430 431 432 433 434 435 436 437 438 439 440 441 442 443 444 445 446 447 448 449 450 451 452 453 454 455 456 457 458 459 460 461 462 463 464 465 466 467 468 469 470 471 472 473 474 475 476 477 478 479 480 481 482 483 484 485 486 487 488 489 490 491 492 493 494 495 496 497 498 499 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 511 512 513 514 515 516 517 518 519 520 521 522 523 524 525 526 527 528 529 530 531 532 533 534 535 536 537 538 539 540 541 542 543 544 545 546 547 548 549 550 551 552 553 554 555 556 557 558 559 560 561 562 563 564 565 566 567 568 569 570 571 572 573 574 575 576 577 578 579 580 581 582 583 584 585 586 587 588 589 590 591 592 593 594 595 596 597 598 599 600 601 602 603 604 605 606 607 608 609 610 611 612 613 614 615 616 617 618 619 620 621 622 623 624 625 626 627 628 629 630 631 632 633 634 635 636 637 638 639 640 641 642 643 644 645 646 647 648 649 650 651 652 653 654 655 656 657 658 659 660 661 662 663 664 665 666 667 668 669 670 671 672 673 674 675 676 677 678 679 680 681 682 683 684 685 686 687 688 689 690 691 692 693 694 695 696 697 698 699 700 701 702 703 704 705 706 707 708 709 710 711 712 713 714 715 716 717 718 719 720 721 722 723 724 725 726 727 728 729 730 731 732 733 734 735 736 737 738 739 740 741 742 743 744 745 746 747 748 749 750 751 752 753 754 755 756 757 758 759 760 761 762 763 764 765 766 767 768 769 770 771 772 773 774 775 776 777 778 779 780 781 782 783 784 785 786 787 788 789 790 791 792 793 794 795 796 797 798 799 800 801 802 803 804 805 806 807 808 809 810 811 812 813 814 815 816 817 818 819 820 821 822 823 824 825 826 827 828 829 830 831 832 833 834 835 836 837 838 839 840 841 842 843 844 845 846 847 848 849 850 851 852 853 854 855 856 857 858 859 860 861 862 863 864 865 866 867 868 869 870 871 872 873 874 875 876 877 878 879 880 881 882 883 884 885 886 887 888 889 890 891 892 893 894 895 896 897 898 899 900 901 902 903 904 905 906 907 908 909 910 911 912 913 914 915 916 917 918 919 920 921 922 923 924 925 926 927 928 929 930 931 932 933 934 935 936 937 938 939 940 941 942 943 944 945 946 947 948 949 950 951 952 953 954 955 956 957 958 959 960 961 962 963 964 965 966 967 968 969 970 971 972 973 974 975 976 977 978 979 980 981 982 983 984 985 986 987 988 989 990 991 992 993 994 995 996 997 998 999 1000"
```

Comment: +1 Hadn't thought of doing that. That'll print to stderr, which makes me think: should it not be a rule that by default solutions have to output to stdout? No quibbering over this solution though.

Comment: @marcog: I'd leave that up to the individual task. Some are ok with error output, some are not. In both cases there are ways to golf it.

Comment: If you want stdout, it's not a huge leap to turn this into the obvious `printf()`

Comment: The thing is, it's not the program that prints the numbers, it's the compiler.  Who'll guarantee it's written in C++?

Comment: This is the only even remotely correct answer.

Answer (score 26):

```
main(){if(printf("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 262 263 264 265 266 267 268 269 270 271 272 273 274 275 276 277 278 279 280 281 282 283 284 285 286 287 288 289 290 291 292 293 294 295 296 297 298 299 300 301 302 303 304 305 306 307 308 309 310 311 312 313 314 315 316 317 318 319 320 321 322 323 324 325 326 327 328 329 330 331 332 333 334 335 336 337 338 339 340 341 342 343 344 345 346 347 348 349 350 351 352 353 354 355 356 357 358 359 360 361 362 363 364 365 366 367 368 369 370 371 372 373 374 375 376 377 378 379 380 381 382 383 384 385 386 387 388 389 390 391 392 393 394 395 396 397 398 399 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 419 420 421 422 423 424 425 426 427 428 429 430 431 432 433 434 435 436 437 438 439 440 441 442 443 444 445 446 447 448 449 450 451 452 453 454 455 456 457 458 459 460 461 462 463 464 465 466 467 468 469 470 471 472 473 474 475 476 477 478 479 480 481 482 483 484 485 486 487 488 489 490 491 492 493 494 495 496 497 498 499 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 511 512 513 514 515 516 517 518 519 520 521 522 523 524 525 526 527 528 529 530 531 532 533 534 535 536 537 538 539 540 541 542 543 544 545 546 547 548 549 550 551 552 553 554 555 556 557 558 559 560 561 562 563 564 565 566 567 568 569 570 571 572 573 574 575 576 577 578 579 580 581 582 583 584 585 586 587 588 589 590 591 592 593 594 595 596 597 598 599 600 601 602 603 604 605 606 607 608 609 610 611 612 613 614 615 616 617 618 619 620 621 622 623 624 625 626 627 628 629 630 631 632 633 634 635 636 637 638 639 640 641 642 643 644 645 646 647 648 649 650 651 652 653 654 655 656 657 658 659 660 661 662 663 664 665 666 667 668 669 670 671 672 673 674 675 676 677 678 679 680 681 682 683 684 685 686 687 688 689 690 691 692 693 694 695 696 697 698 699 700 701 702 703 704 705 706 707 708 709 710 711 712 713 714 715 716 717 718 719 720 721 722 723 724 725 726 727 728 729 730 731 732 733 734 735 736 737 738 739 740 741 742 743 744 745 746 747 748 749 750 751 752 753 754 755 756 757 758 759 760 761 762 763 764 765 766 767 768 769 770 771 772 773 774 775 776 777 778 779 780 781 782 783 784 785 786 787 788 789 790 791 792 793 794 795 796 797 798 799 800 801 802 803 804 805 806 807 808 809 810 811 812 813 814 815 816 817 818 819 820 821 822 823 824 825 826 827 828 829 830 831 832 833 834 835 836 837 838 839 840 841 842 843 844 845 846 847 848 849 850 851 852 853 854 855 856 857 858 859 860 861 862 863 864 865 866 867 868 869 870 871 872 873 874 875 876 877 878 879 880 881 882 883 884 885 886 887 888 889 890 891 892 893 894 895 896 897 898 899 900 901 902 903 904 905 906 907 908 909 910 911 912 913 914 915 916 917 918 919 920 921 922 923 924 925 926 927 928 929 930 931 932 933 934 935 936 937 938 939 940 941 942 943 944 945 946 947 948 949 950 951 952 953 954 955 956 957 958 959 960 961 962 963 964 965 966 967 968 969 970 971 972 973 974 975 976 977 978 979 980 981 982 983 984 985 986 987 988 989 990 991 992 993 994 995 996 997 998 999 1000")){}}
```

Comment: @John: He probably cut and pasted it. This isn't lines from your school. :-P :-P :-P

Comment: @Chris: Good Point.  :-P

Comment: I can't believe 4 people voted for this, this is wrong, prints till 999.

Comment: @st0le, oops better fix that before i get downvotes

Comment: @gnibbler Can you post the program that generated that program? ;)

Comment: @muntoo: He probably used Alexandru's program.  ;)

Comment: This is still wrong- main has no return type.

Answer (score 12):

Simple and almost idiomatic:

```
#include <iostream>

void loop(int low, int high)
{
  if ( low <= high                   &&
       std::cout << low << std::endl &&
       (loop(low+1, high), false) )
  {}
}

int main()
{
  if (loop(1, 1000), false) {}
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void) {
    if (char *p = (char *) malloc(10000U)) {
        if (__LINE__ < 106 && printf("%d\n", __LINE__ - 5)) {
            if (FILE *fp = fopen(__FILE__ ".tmp", "w")) {
                if (putc('\n', fp) &&
                    fwrite(p, 1U,
                           fread(p, 1U, 10000U, fopen(__FILE__, "r")), fp) &&
                    fclose(fp) ||
                    rename(__FILE__ ".tmp", __FILE__) ||
                    system("g++ " __FILE__ " && exec ./a.out")) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ouch, painful.. Why even use a file?

Answer (score 7):

Very similar to other solutions, but with a minor variation: The step variable is declared in the `if` condition:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
if (int x = 1)
    while (x <= 1000 && std::cout << x++ << std::endl) {}
}
```

Comment: You ain't returning an int...

Comment: @Vercas: Undefined behavior is allowed here :)

Comment: @Vercas, `main()` has implicit `return 0;` in C++.

Answer (score 6):

This works great on my Linux machine:

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    if (system("seq 1 1000")){}
}
```

I know, I know, ...it's not portable.

Comment: `seq 1000` suffices.

Answer (score 6):

```c++
   /* No semicolons - or sense - //
  //  but at least there's      //
 //   undefined behaviour      //
*/                            //
#define __ if
#define ___ int
#define ____ std
#define ______ &&
#define _______ {
#define ________ (
#define _________ )
#define __________ }
#define ___________ .
#define ____________ ,
#define _____________ <
#define ______________ >
#define _______________ ::
#define zero 0
#define five 5
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
___ _ ________ ____ _______________
vector
_____________ ___ ______________ _____ _________ _______ __ ________ ____ _______________
distance
________ _____ ___________
emplace
________ _____ ___________
end
________ _________ ____________
zero
_________ ____________ _____ ___________
end
________ _________ _________ ______
printf
________
"%d\n\0 I may have got a bit too carried away with the obfuscation."
____________ _____ ___________
size
________ _________ _________ _____________
five
______ _ ________ _____ _________ _________ _______ __________ __________ ___
main
________ _________ _______ __ ________ _ ________ _______ __________ _________ _________  _______ __________ __________
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVNNb8IwDL3nVzyBxjY0KJddEOK@y34BUpSmLkRqk6pJQWPab@/SMUpbCp3mQ2o/P380sWWWzbZSliWAYIp3A0upkiYx2mIGk3tbW/JqEDBPCYCwcBAOCQnr4HaU06PFj1SUioFCRxQrTRFC2om9MkVeM6YB7ognjE@x4Bwqblje1K5pc1gXtQAPTSYdhOOzi3A8XUEcz9cYx1cPyDHvQzleemGOVT/Osb7h4Fgua9eRcoNFbcZqT3hlY6VlUkSElfS3oMy6gexJOpOvWZWIX366PhrCTlzWrn5NBG9H4/IdKBAp64SWxG6l8hxKs0QMUHTEusU71Vh1U6zf94@MvxrLcj93cU1lo4doozcLvCEVH/DjTdgavxIIld8HYyBFnis/@@Lg/QfldtWWwIRxYaVwyuj5iA30ZtWR/tLcmV8NBTt7MPRorefj/SpLhdLsbmSjDv6UuKHdb6AsvwE)

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <iostream>

void main()
{
   if (int i = 1)
   {
      while (std::cout << i << std::endl, i++ < 1000) {}
   }
}
```

Comment: wheres the i coming from?

Comment: Fixed and compiled with dmc.

Comment: `main` returns `int`, always

Answer (score 5):

*Almost* any regular-looking program can do, 
(no compiler specification necessary), like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 void main(int argc, char*argv[]) 
{
if(argc=1000)
   while(argc-- && printf("%d ",1000-argc)) {}
}
```

can be formulated with C++ iostream in many different ways:

```
 #include <iostream>
 void main(int argc, char*argv[]) 
{
 if( ! (argc ^= argc) ) 
    while( argc++<1000 && std::cout.operator<<(argc) ) { 

    }
}
```

Comment: `main` returns `int`, always.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int write_code(std::string str, std::ofstream out = std::ofstream())
{
    if (((
        out.open("my-thousand-tmp.cpp"),
        out) << str,
        out).close(),
        system("g++ -Wall -W -O3 my-thousand-tmp.cpp && exec ./a.out")
    ) {}

}

static int add_semicolons(std::string str, size_t i = 0)
{
    while (i < str.size())
        if (str[i++] == ':' && str[i-1]++) {}
    if (write_code(str)) {}
}

int main()
{
    if (add_semicolons(
        "#include <iostream>\n"
        "using namespace std:\n"
        "\n"
        "int main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "\tfor (int i = 1: i <= 1000: i++)\n"
        "\t\tcout << i << endl:\n"
        "\treturn 0:\n"
        "}\n"
    )) {}
}
```

I tried to initialize std::ofstream out by passing it as a parameter (i.e. `write_code(str, std::ofstream())` ), but apparently, the copy constructor is private, and an expression like this can't be passed by reference.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    while(errno++ < 1000 && printf("%d ", errno)){}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define __INTMAX_TYPE__ struct C { C(int x) { if (x == 1001?(puts(""),true):(printf("%d ",x),C(x+1),false)) {} } }
#include <stdint.h>
main(){if(intmax_t(1),false){}}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 57 bytes

This takes advantage that the number of operands is always 1. (Not a codegolf, but I want to golf it...)

Thx to @ceilingcat for replacing printf with `__builtin_printf`.

```cpp
main(int i){while(1001-i&&__builtin_printf("%d ",i++)){}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/PzcxM08jM69EIVOzujwjMydVw9DAwFA3U00tPj6pNDOnJDMvvqAIqCBNQ0k1RUFJJ1NbW1Ozurb2/38A)

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 43 bytes

They are also [posting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9245/85052) C answers, I assume?

```c
main(i){while(1001-i&&printf("%d ",i++)){}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPI1OzujwjMydVw9DAwFA3U02toCgzryRNQ0k1RUFJJ1NbW1Ozurb2/38A)

Answer (score 2):

I just saw the last comment…
However I believe this is valid C++:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char**) {
  while (argc != 1001
    and std::printf("%d, ", argc++)) {}
}
```

[compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/cnK3zTrnd)

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(int i)
{
while(printf("%d ",i) && i<=1000 && i++){}
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work in C++, you have to include ```cstdio```,

Answer (score 1):

C++11 based solution using a lambda function:

```
/* golf.cpp */
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    if( [] (int from, int to) -> bool {
        while(std::cout << from << " " && ++from <= to
            || std::cout << std::endl && false) {}
    } (1, 1000) ) {}
}
```

Compiles and works:

```
$ g++ --version | head -n1
g++ (GCC) 4.8.2 20131017 (Red Hat 4.8.2-1)
...
$ g++ -std=c++11 golf.cpp -o golf
$ ./golf
```

Bonus 1: Adjusting the range to be printed is as easy as editing the two parameters of the call.

Bonus 2: Output terminated by a new line.

Answer (score 1):

Your run-o'-the-mill recursion-based answer.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int i, char *k[]) {
    if(
        k != NULL && (
            i = 0
        ),
        std::cout << i << ' ',
        i < 1e3 &&
            main(i + 1, NULL)
    ) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++ with templates

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

template<int THOU> void f() { while (printf("%d\n", THOU), f<THOU+1>(), 0) {} }
template<> void f<1001>() { while(exit(0), 0) {} }
int main()
{
    while (f<1>(), 0) {}
}
```

Notes:

- Linux version 3.2.0-58-generic (buildd@allspice) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) ) #88-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 3 17:37:58 UTC 2013
- 64 bit (amd64) version of Kubuntu